# absolute value in TCL

Tags: tcl

What is the function to get absolute value of a expr statement.
For example `expr [$a - $b ]`.
Now the solution can be -ve or +positive number. But I want the +ve value out.

I want to use it like `if { |$diff_a| > 0 & |$diff_b| >0 } {`
....

Im using tcl 8.4.

Comment: Have you even googled for this?  Just googling for your question title comes up with the answer and many examples.

Comment: abs (x) does not work in tcl 8.4. other solution are like if { $diff_a > 0 } { puts $diff_a } else { puts - $diff_a }

Comment: did you just typo?  Or are you really trying abc()?

Comment: @user2095095: are you sure about that? The 8.4 man page lists `abs` as a valid function. http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/expr.htm#M21

Comment: @user2095095: what error do you get when you try to use abs()?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add, that the 'abs' command can only be used within a mathematical expression in Tcl, so the correct example would be:

```
if {[expr abs($diff_a)] > 0} {...}
```

For further information I refer to the expr man page as specified in the answer above.

Comment: This answer is subtly incorrect. While it's true it can only be used with a mathematical expression, you don't need to call `expr` inside an if statement. `if` already treats it's first argument as an expression, so `if {abs($diff_a) > 0}` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the `abs` function:

```
if {abs($diff_a) > 0 ...} ...
```

Note that `abs` only works in the context of an expression (eg: by calling `expr`), but also note that the first argument to `if` is evaluated as an expression.

`abs` is documented on the [expr](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/expr.htm#M21) man page in versions prior to tcl 8.4. Starting with 8.5 it's on the [mathfunc](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M6) man page.

Comment: thanks just realized it work. I was trying to set abs on the expr function and that was not working. How can I point a line next to current line in TCL after this if loop is true.(Im reading a file & doing some mathematical operation in it)

Comment: @user What does “set abs on the expr function” look like in code?